# aggregate or group data in google bigquery SQL to capture the event category , revenue, item quantity

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to combine all the result into one column?

```
the sql I used is as follwings:
SELECT distinct
  hits.transaction.transactionId,
  Date,
  totals.pageviews,
  hits.item.itemQuantity,
  hits.transaction.transactionRevenue,
  totals.bounces,
  fullvisitorid,
  totals.timeOnSite,
  device.browser,
  device.deviceCategory,
  trafficSource.source,
  channelGrouping,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory ,
  device.operatingSystem


FROM
  `atomic-life-148403.126959513.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits

WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN REPLACE(CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AS STRING), '-','')
  AND CONCAT('intraday_', REPLACE(CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) AS STRING), '-','')) 

  and date>="20170401" and date<="20170403"


  ORDER BY
  date  DESC
```

However, the result I have is as below:
[image]

The issue is that itemquantity, transaction revenue, and eventcategory is not in the same row. How to solve the issue to aggregate or group the data as one

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but if the goal is to have a single row for each `(eventCategory, date)` combination, you can use `ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(...))` to combine the rest of the columns into a single value for each row. For example,

```
SELECT
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  date,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
    hits.transaction.transactionId,
    hits.item.itemQuantity,
    hits.transaction.transactionRevenue,
    hits.page.pagePath,
    totals.pageviews,
    totals.bounces,
    fullvisitorid,
    totals.timeOnSite,
    device.browser,
    device.deviceCategory,
    trafficSource.source,
    channelGrouping,
    device.operatingSystem
  )) AS event_info
FROM
  `atomic-life-148403.126959513.ga_sessions_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)) AND
    FORMAT_DATE('intraday_%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE()) AND
  date BETWEEN "20170401" AND "20170403"
GROUP BY eventCategory, date
ORDER BY date DESC;
```